# PC from/to Android voice communication without Internet

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, voip

I want to call my PC using my Android phone (and vice versa) without internet. PC to Android or Android to PC, not just Android to Android. I think it is possible, but not sure if there is a program like that.

What apps do I need to install both on PC and Android phone?

Comment: Do you mean calling inside a WiFi without internet access, or without any data connection?

Answer (score 0):

OK, just use [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/overview). That's the app the old answer recommended, as you can just use the same program on Win/OSX/Linux/Android/iOS. You don't need internet, but you do still need to have IP connectivity between the devices (if one can ping the other then you're good to go).

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you know of apps that will specifically help the OP then please provide links etc. I can't see how the answer will solve this to be honest, as it's phone to phone VoIP, rather than what the OP is attempting.

Comment: If the goal is to talk directly between PCs, Android devices, or a combination, then SIP is a good route to go. The question I linked to was about Android to Android SIP but, as the comments there discussed, SIP can be P2P or use a server, and SIP clients on an Android phone or PC are interoperable. Those clients for Android solve the Android half of this question, although some Googling also turned up Linphone, which runs on Win/OSX/Linux/Android/iOS: http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/overview